# <<From csv to array to database issue: not loading entire fail or failing

Tags: php, csv

I need some help over here... what I try to do is to read a csv file (which is already converted from xls) then get all lines and put every field of a line into db

```
name,lastname,idprod
name,lastname,idprod
name,lastname,idprod
```

the issue might be that some fields are empty,
but after launching the script it starts working for like 1883 lines and put them in database, then the

`$row["productid"] ." - ". $productid ."";` 
 starts outputting empty value

`here -`

for the rest of the lines

Sorry for code in pastebin, this editor won't allow me to post this question with code saying some issues...

```
<?php
$rowe = 0;
$exploded;
$data;
$ass = 0;
$hardcore[0][0];
$swag = 0;
if (($handle = fopen("price_list_EN.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $ass = 0;
    $swag++;
    while (($linebyline = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        //$linebyline = explode(",", $linebyline);

        $hardcore[$rowe][$ass] = $linebyline[$ass];
        //echo $linebyline[$ass];
        $exploded[$rowe][$ass] = $hardcore[$rowe][$ass];
        //echo $exploded[$rowe][$ass];

        //while (($explode = fgetcsv($linebyline, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
        {
            $num = count($data);
            if ($ass == count($linebyline)){
                echo "<br>";
                $ass = 0;
                $rowe++;
            }else{
                $ass++;
            }
        }
        //}
        fclose($handle);
    }
    //$linebyline = explode("\n", $_POST['message']);
    //$linebyline = explode("\n", $data2);
    //echo count($data2);
    $imo=0;
    $normovalue=0;
    $normovalue2=0;
    $normovalue3=0;
    for ($i=0;$i<30000;$i++){
        if ($exploded[$i][0] == ''){
            $imo = $i;
        }
    }

    for ($rowe=0;$rowe<$imo;$rowe++){
        for ($ass=0;$ass<9;$ass++){
            //$exploded = explode(";", $linebyline[$i]);
            $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
            if (!$link) {
                die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
            }

            // make foo the current db
            $db_selected = mysql_select_db('moday', $link);
            if (!$db_selected) {
                die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
            }
        }
        if ($exploded[$rowe][0] !== "" || $exploded[$rowe][4] !== "" || 
            $exploded[$rowe][3] !== "" || $exploded[$rowe][1] !== ""){
            $productid = $exploded[$rowe][0];
            $price = round($exploded[$rowe][4],2);
            $disponibilita = $exploded[$rowe][3];
            $indir = "null";
            $descrizione = $exploded[$rowe][1];

            $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "moday");

            $sql = "SELECT productid from data where productid='$productid'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO 
         data(productid,price,disponibilita,indir,descrizione) 
         values('$productid','$price','$disponibilita','$indir','$descrizione')")
                    or die("Query non valida: " . mysql_error());
                $normovalue++;
            }else{

                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    if ($row["productid"] == $productid){
                        echo "here ". $row["productid"] ." - ". $productid ."";
                        if ("$exploded[$rowe][0] == '' || $exploded[$rowe][1] == 
             '' || $exploded[$rowe][3] == '' || $exploded[$rowe][4] == '' || 
           $exploded[$rowe][2] == ''|| $exploded[$rowe][5] hh "){
                            echo $exploded[$rowe][0];
                            echo $rowe;

                        }
                        echo "<br /> \n";
                        $sql2 = "UPDATE data SET price='$price', 
             disponibilita='$disponibilita' where productid='$productid'";
                        $normovalue2++;
                        $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

                    }else{
                    }
                }
            }

            /*$risultato = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 
              data(productid,price,disponibilita,indir,descrizione) 
              values('$productid','$price','$disponibilita','$indir','$descrizione')")
              or die("Query non valida: " . mysql_error());
            */
            //echo "<br /> \n"
        }
    }
    $normovalue3 = $normovalue + $normovalue2;
    echo "N.1 is $normovalue 2 is $normovalue2 3 is $normovalue3";
    ?>
```

Comment: hey nice banner effect!!! wow...  you can remove that blockquote now; thanks

Comment: and you felt that a 3rd party fetch is in order? it isn't. Put your code in the question. thanks

Comment: *"Sorry for code in pastebin, this editor won't allow me to post this question with code saying some issues"* - well there's a reason for it and you should follow the instructions for it.

Comment: `LOAD DATA INFILE` no need for all this code

Comment: done.. sorry @Fred-ii-

Comment: Your braces aren't balanced properly.

Comment: `if ("$exploded[$rowe][0] ==...")` Why do you have a string literal in your `if` condition? That's always going to evaluate to `true`

Comment: If you want to test if any of the fields are empty, use `if(in_array("", $exploded[$rowe]))`

Comment: If you want to read a CSV file, use `fgetcsv()`. Your code won't work properly if there are quoted fields.

Comment: You should also use prepared statements instead of substituting variables, otherwise you'll have problems if there are single quotes in the data.

Comment: You should use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` instead of doing a `SELECT` followed by `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `$result` into the database, as you desire:

```
<?php
$csv = "Chris,Garcia,1\nJohn,Doe,2\nJames,Smith,3";

foreach(explode("\n", $csv) as $key => $value) {
    $result = explode(",", $value);

    echo "Name: " . $result[0] . ", Lastname: " . $result[1] . ", ID: " . $result[2] . "\n";
}

exit();
?>
```